# Strange AFNetworking behaviour: GET request gets an old packet

Tags: afnetworking

I'm experiencing a very strange issue with AFNetworking and JSONRequestOperation. I'm investigating it further at the moment, but so far I've got some results I cannot explain:

What I do:
1) Building xcode project and running in on my ipad
2) Sending JSONRequestOperation to servlet
3) Getting my json object 
4) Turning off my server
5) Sending JSONRequestOperation again (to offlined server)
. . .
6) JSONRequestOperation calls "success" callback and gives me the same json object. Instead of calling "failed" callback, because of not responding server.

More than that: 
If I'm rolling system time on ipad 1 hour back (on purpose) instead of turning my server off - I'm getting same the situation: JSONRequestOperation starts to give me the same object that was received while system time was still correct.

In the second case I launched Wireshark and saw no GET request from my ipad to my server at all.

In the same time
POST and DELETE requests working correctly: they fail if server is stopped, and system time changes don't affect them.

Comment: Do you have any cache control headers on your response? If the cache is valid you will get a cached version of your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFNetworking uses NSURLRequest, which caches requests by default.

You can set the [`cachePolicy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequestCachePolicy) property to determine how your requests are cached.  By default, it will follow the HTTP spec, which allows your server to send HTTP headers that tell the client when and how long to cache for.  I recommend you keep this setting, and update the cache headers on your server to tell the client not to cache requests you don't want cached.

If you don't want any requests cached, you can specify `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` or `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData`.  The latter also informs proxies / intermediaries not to provide you with a cached response.

Just remember if you set this up by overriding all requests in `[AFHTTPClient -requestWithMethod:
             path:
       parameters:]` your app will run slower because it will download data even if no new data is available.

Comment: thanks. now i understand how this weird stuff with time changing affects networking.